# jQuery is adding class and clicking but behaving as click at the same time

Tags: jquery, html

I have a back button that is uses the following HTML

```
<div class="back-from-professors level-one">Back</div>
```

I use the following jQuery to apply a back action

```
jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click', '.back-from-professors.level-one', function() {
    jQuery('.professor').removeClass('show');
    jQuery('.professor-list').hide();
    jQuery('.research-box-inner-sections-container').show();
    jQuery('.capability-list').removeClass('temporary-hide');
});
```

I then want to apply the following when

```
jQuery('.professor-list').on('click','.professor.show', function() {

    jQuery(this).parent().find('.back-from-professors').addClass('level-two');
    jQuery(this).parent().find('.back-from-professors').removeClass('level-one');       
    jQuery(this).next().addClass('show');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('show');

}); 

jQuery('.professor-list').on('click','.back-from-professors.level-two', function() {

    jQuery(this).parent().find('.grey-list-item.professor').addClass('show');
    jQuery(this).parent().find('.grey-list-professor-details').removeClass('show');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('level-two');
    alert('test');
    jQuery(this).addClass('level-one');     

});
```

However when I click `.back-from-professors.level-two` its doing as expected and then alerting `test`. It then adds the class `level-one` but THEN also performs the action from my first jQuery code above, i.e. it applies the actions of `jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click', '.back-from-professors.level-one', function() {});`

Is this supposed to happen with `.on()`?

I am able to replicate the problem here...
http://jsfiddle.net/tb8uLpnL/4/ (jsfiddle updated)

Comment: is .back-from-professors.level-two inside .back-from-professors.level-one? could be propagating up. try stopProgation inside .back-from-professors.level-two.

Comment: No they are the same element so I wouldnt see why that would happen. Its unusual as it works perfectly as expected up until straight after `alert('test');`, and then rather than just simply adding the class, it seems to do all the things in my first jQuery function

Comment: I added `event.stopPropagation();` after `jQuery(this).addClass('level-one');` but no luck

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tb8uLpnL/2/ problem replicated here

Comment: sorry , ive a slightly more up to date one here http://jsfiddle.net/tb8uLpnL/4/ just a text change for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `.professor-list` is inside `.research-box-container`. so when you click on `back`, it bubbles up to the events attached to `.professor-list` which you catch with :-

```
jQuery('.professor-list').on('click','.back-from-professors.level-two', function() {
```

which you then add `.level-one` too. then when it bubbles up again to the next element `.research-box-container` the events attached

```
jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click', '.back-from-professors.level-one', function() {
```

finds an element within with the class `.level-one`.

the easiest fix is too attach both to `.research-box-container`.

So:-

```
jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click', '.back-from-professors.level-one', function() {

jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click','.back-from-professors.level-two', function() {
```

Comment: Wow perfect , thank you! Quick question, even though the issue is resolved I still dont fully understand why it decided to trigger `jQuery('.research-box-container').on('click', '.back-from-professors.level-one', function()` after the class is added. I understand that because `.professor-list` is inside `.research-box-container` its clicking the two of them , but I would have thought that `.back-from-professors.level-one` still wouldnt "exist" yet if you get me!

Comment: I mean exist for that particular click

Comment: The click propagates UP from the element. So, when its at .professor-list you add .level-one. Then the event moves UP to .research-box-container. now it finds .level-one.